# How to allow any attributes from unknown namespaces?

Tags: xsd, xml-namespaces

I'm writing an XML Schema. It validates elements and their attributes from a single namespace.
How do I allow any attributes from other namespaces while still validating the non-prefixed attributes?
The list of other attributes and their namespaces is unknown at the time of writing the schema.
The XML is human-written and I would like to minimize the possibility of typos in attribute names. The attributes from other namespaces will used scarcely so it's ok not to validate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsd:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />
```